# How to remove ASP comments-only blocks in Python (on Sublime Text 2)?

Tags: python, regex, asp-classic, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I'm playing with Python Regex, in order to clean the code produced for Classic ASP pages.

I need to remove SINGLE LINE or MULTILINE ASP comment blocks.
(the ASP comment lines usually start with a **quote**).

I aim to match blocks containing no executable code, but only blocks containing comments.
Wether there is tabs or spaces in the comments, I need to replace these 3 strings by nothing :

**String 1 :**

```
<%'     This multiline comment starts with two TAB characters after the quote
'and continues here
%>
```

**String 2 :**

```
<%    'This multiline comment starts with SPACES characters before the quote
        'and continues here, with TABS before the quote
    '     and with spaces before and after the quote
%>
```

**String 3 :**

```
<%'This single line comment should at least be easy to remove%>
```

***I've tried the following Regex, but with only a partial success … :-/***

```
output = re.sub(r'(<%(.*?)\')(.*?)(%>)', r'', output)
output = re.sub(r'<%(\t*|\s*)\'(.*)(%>)', r'', output)
```

Could you give me a little advice ?
Many thanks for your help : any tip will be highly appreciated ;-)

Comment: Maybe a simple `<%[\S\s]*?%>` is how to parse it. Comment style markup is usually first delimiter to the very next delimiter.

Comment: Thanks sln :) Your Regex works but will target ANY block of ASP code, including those containing useful code. 
I think the strategy to adopt is to match every line that is : 
1.- starting with a \n (newline) , 
2.- followed by spaces or tabs , 
3.- then having a quote. 
It could eventually be done with three consecutive regex, in order to "more easily" find the quote (my Holy Grail !)
Infortunately I cannot succeed to make the proper Regex string .. ouch !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting over.
Assumptions:

If the line begins with a single quote, its a comment.
Get all blocks with *only* quoted lines.
Dot `.` metachar does *not* match newline.

`<%(?:\s*'.*)+\s*%>`

Formatted

```
 <%
 (?: \s* ' .* )+
 \s* 
 %>
```

That matches all your samples.

**Edit**

For safety though, you should use a negative assertion before that dot.

`<%(?:\s*'(?:(?!%>).)*)+\s*%>`

Formatted

```
 <%
 (?:
      \s* ' 
      (?:
           (?! %> )
           . 
      )*
 )+
 \s* 
 %>
```

Comment: Hi sln, You're very very close ! It totally works, except it also match to blocks that : 1. Start with a quote (with or without spaces), but also 2. containing useful code. I think your code would just need to detect if there is nothing else than a \n or spaces before the closing %>, and It will be perfect !

Comment: Oh, I see. So the commented lines are just preceded with a quote.

Comment: @AlexLaforge - Try the new regex.

Comment: Hi again sln : IT WORKS, IT ROCKS !
You **really** are a life saver ! Your mind is totally amazing : your assumptions are completely right, and I had forgotten to express them so clearly : _Each line MUST start with a quote_, that was **the clue**. You succeeded in reading between my lines :-) I'm not really good but not really sucking with Regex, but YOU definitely beat me, without any doubt ^!^ Your profile was not lying : it says that you are a Regex expert : I totally agree. Thank you very much and greetings !! (I've marked your answer as the good one)

Comment: @AlexLaforge - Welcome to SO. Be warned though, people get a big head with that kind of talk...

Comment: You can ! ^!^ I know how to recognize quality when I meet it, and you are ! You deserve what I told you, so take it, take it !

Comment: You're right ! Thank your for your Safety check EDIT !